# How to use explicit wait in python selenium?

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to parse the following url, "https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/document-detail/P179109?type=projects", using selenium in python, to do the following:
1- Go to URL
2- Wait for page to either
Load table of documents
Load element "No data available." such in this example "https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/document-detail/P179227?type=projects"

3- Parse the content of table of documents

I tried the multiple codes, though this is the final:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

urls = ['https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/document-detail/P179109?type=projects','https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/document-detail/P179278?type=projects'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
l1=[]
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//tr[@_ngcontent-c2=""]/td[@_ngcontent-c2=""]"),(By.CSS_SELECTOR("div.procurement_notices[_ngcontent-c2=""]"))))
    # driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody')
    l1.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//tr[@_ngcontent-c2=""]/td[@_ngcontent-c2=""]').text)
```

Comment: How can you _Parse the content of table_ in a `l1=[]`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic [X-Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).
Here is a way to get that information you're after from the first page you mention, by scraping the API endpoint accessed by that page, in order to hydrate the document list:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = 'https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/wds?format=json&includepublicdocs=1&fl=docna,lang,docty,repnb,docdt,doc_authr,available_in&os=0&rows=20&os=0&proid=P179109&apilang=en&fct=countryname'
r = requests.get(api_url)
docs_list = []
for k, v in r.json()['documents'].items():
    docs_list.append(v)
df = pd.DataFrame(docs_list)
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    id  docna   docty   lang    entityids   repnb   docdt   display_title   pdfurl  listing_relative_url    url_friendly_title  new_url     guid    available_in    fullavailablein     url
0   33872193    {'0': {'docna': 'Concept Project Information D...   Project Information Document    English     {'entityid': '33872193'}    PIDC34319   2022-07-22T00:00:00Z    Concept Project Information Document\n ...  http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/0999...   /projects/documents/2022/07/33872193/concept-p...   http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/0999...   2022/07/33872193/P17910909e91120a0a1cc04f1ca93...   099915007222220480  English     []  http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/0999...
1   33871622    {'0': {'docna': 'Concept Environmental and Soc...   Environmental and Social Review Summary     English     {'entityid': '33871622'}    ESRSC02925  2022-07-21T00:00:00Z    Concept Environmental and Social\n ...  http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/0991...   /projects/documents/2022/07/33871622/concept-e...   http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/0991...   2022/07/33871622/P1791090dbf46c0c30993306f24d6...   099145007212228304  English     []  http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/0991...
2   33862268    {'0': {'docna': 'Minutes of a Virtual Meeting ...   Minutes     English     {'entityid': '090224b08a420d2a_2_0'}    173649  2022-05-24T00:00:00Z    Minutes of a Virtual Meeting of the\n ...   http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/5814...   /projects/documents/2022/05/33862268/minutes-v...   http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/5814...   2022/05/33862268/Minutes-of-a-Virtual-Meeting-...   581451657570685786  English     []  http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/5814...
3   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

In regards to your (likely nonrelevant for the issue at hand) question, [here is the Selenium documentation for Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/).